# What is difference between jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress and haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I found that there are two ingress-controllers, one is `jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress` and the other is `haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress` What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress, it is tagged "hacktoberfest" so possibly this one is that user's work on on the application at a [hackathon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hackathon).

At a guess, I'm also assuming https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress is the official one.